# Transfer Function for active filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, low-pass, active-filter

Not too sure why, but I can’t seem to figure out the transfer function for the filter in question below. Can’t isolate Vout/Vin fully, there’s a straggling Vin that I can’t move over. Any thoughts?

[image: Filter in question]

Comment: RS produces a VIN-dependent current. What's your goal here?

Comment: Look at the transfer function of a non-inverting amplifier and consider impedances made of the parallel associations of \$R_3C_2\$ and \$R_sR_1\$. The -5-V line is 0 V in ac (hence the parallel combination with \$R_1\$) if that is what is causing you problem.

Comment: Use the rule: sum of currents AWAY from node = 0, otherwise it’s easy to make sign errors. You have at least one such error. Don’t be in a hurry to use numerical values; use symbols until the end.

Comment: Do you really intend to start with KCL? Such a circuit is a basic one and can be analyzed using the well-known gain formula for a simple non-inverting gain stage.

Comment: Transfer functions assume zero initial conditions, so there will be a problem with the -5V source if it's an initial condition. Superposition is one way out of that problem.

Comment: @VerbalKint So basically make it 1+((R3||C2)/(RS||R1))?

Comment: Oui, correct. You can see that the 200k resistance has little action over the 1k so in ac, the dc gain is roughly 40 dB or 101 and in high frequencies, as \$C_2\$ shorts \$R_3\$ the gain is 1 or 0 dB. For the dc transfer characteristic or the dc operating point, then the shift brought by \$R_s\$ plays a role.

Comment: @Zashiony If the input is biased around 0 V, as the examples shown so far are, then yes you will have a combination of a high-pass with gain = 1 near daylight and a low-pass with gain = 101.5 near DC. However, the low-pass gain is bias-dependent. So if your Vin has a DC bias to it then the low-pass gain won't be so simple.

Answer (score -1):

For help, you should also simulate this.

See the behavior of "voltage shift" ... One can see the "DC" and "AC" parts.

[image]

Alternatively, the "AC" part can be shown also like this ... which shows also the "AC frequency transfer function".

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words ?

Comment: I'm aware of what the Bode plot will look like via simulation - I've already done that. I just need to figure out the numeric transfer function equation at this point.

Comment: Ok, Good point. Then you have the two "corners" of the function ...